# How can I change Typo3 BodyTag, when a constant is not empty

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to set a class and a style attribute in the Body-Tag. But only if a Constant is set.

Constant:

```
page.theme.bodybackgroundpicture = fileadmin/pageBackground.png
```

Setup:

```
temp.body = COA
temp.body {
  10 = TEXT
  10.value = {$page.theme.bodybackgroundpicture}
  10.stdWrap.wrap = <body class="background" style="background-image: url(|)">
  10.stdWrap.wrap.override = <body>
  10.stdWrap.wrap.override.ifEmpty = {$page.theme.bodybackgroundpicture}
}

page.bodyTagCObject < temp.body
```

It should be

```
<body class="background" style="background-image: url(fileadmin/pageBackground.png)">
```

or if constant is empty

```
<body>
```

But this don't work, where is my Error? Can anybody help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work because the .wrap part is always a string and not of type stdWrap itself, so it has no override propery. You could create two objects with different if conditions like that

```
temp.body = COA
temp.body {
  10 = TEXT
  10.value = {$page.theme.bodybackgroundpicture}
  10.stdWrap.wrap = <body class="background" style="background-image: url(|)">
  10.if.isTrue = {$page.theme.bodybackgroundpicture}
  20 = TEXT
  20.value = <body>
  20.if.isFalse = {$page.theme.bodybackgroundpicture}
}
```

This should also work:

```
10.value =  <body class="background" style="background-image: url({$page.theme.bodybackgroundpicture})">
```